# Why doesn't React component show up on the app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import, components, jsx

I've created a component (in spotifyPlaylist.js) and as the first step I  am trying to have the app show this component as a list box next to others, however this new component doesn't even show when I inspect the page (screenshot below). I'm a newbie so any feedback helps, thank you!

1. Created the component in ./spotifyList/spotifyList

   ```
   import './spotifyPlaylist.css';

   export class spotifyPlaylist extends React.Component {
     render() {
       return (
         <div className="spotifyPlaylist">
           <input defaultValue="Existing Playlist" />
         </div>);}}
   ```
2. Imported it in App.js (it's the main file)

`import { spotifyPlaylist } from '../spotifyPlaylist/spotifyPlaylist';`

3. Added  into the App component's render.

   ````
   ... 
   render() {
   return (
     <div>
       <div className="App">
         <SearchBar onSearch={this.search} />
         <div className="App-playlist">
           <SearchResults
             onAdd={this.addTrack}
             searchResults={this.state.searchResults}
           />
           <Playlist
             playlistName={this.state.playlistName}
             playlistTracks={this.state.playlistTracks}
             onRemove={this.removeTrack}
             onNameChange={this.updatePlaylistName}
             onSave={this.savePlaylist}
           />
           <spotifyPlaylist />
           </div>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
   );
   }
   }```
   ````

[image]

[image: Image shows there's no component called spotifyPlaylist]

Comment: There is nothing to show because... input has no value...div is just a container...what do you expect to see?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In react component names have to start with a capital letter to be used in jsx, so ether rename it on the import:

```
import { spotifyPlaylist as SpotifyPlaylist } from '../spotifyPlaylist/spotifyPlaylist';
```

AND

```
<SpotifyPlaylist />
```

OR rename it all together